# RSpec JUnit formatter output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, junit, rspec

We're using the RSpec JUnit formatter. It would be much better if if would report the file path and line number of the test. Currently it has the "class name" which it formats as something similar to the file path, but with periods instead of slashes. It's just not useful that way. Perhaps it's trying to look like a Java object reference. It's just not. Any way I can change that without having to fork?

Comment: The line numbers are reported within the stack trace for any failures. Why do you need line numbers on the passing specs?

Comment: I guess you mean they are reported by the other formatters? In our environment that is in a very different place, and so to make the JUnit report display useful, they need to be in it. Otherwise it's just not worth it, and we should just use the regular report. But in our env on Jenkins and now on CircleCI, the JUnit report is prioritized and we want to use it.

Comment: No - the line numbers appear in my JUnit report.

Comment: I guess we have more complicated tests. The line numbers in the trace are such that we have to go look at multiple different places, and then find the beginning of the test block. Just silly to not include the test line number in the reference to the test.

Comment: @Jon What line numbers appear in your JUnit report? The line number of the test? Or a long stack trace that might have some line numbers in your test block? RSpec default output has a place where it reports one line number that is unambiguously the location of the beginning of the block. That is what I want in some part of the JUnit output.

Comment: As part of the body of a failure message, I get the line number of the failing part of the spec - `./spec/models/cart_spec.rb:514`. Pretty sure this is just standard behaviour.

Comment: @Jon And it's not just one line, right? It makes it easy to find the problem, but there's not a clear line in the output that can be parsed and listed as the line number of the test that is failing.

Comment: I'd argue that the rest of the content is pretty useful context. Why don't you just provide the whole thing? Alternatively, it wouldn't be hugely complex to regex out the bit you want.

Comment: @Jon Sure, it can be useful. I am trying to have an unambiguous indication of which test is failing, and that is not trivial to get out of that formatted text. And also it's just lying to say that the class name is that file path with the slashes replaced by periods. I try not to lie in my output.